# Jquery Probably me misunderstanding the this selector

Tags: jquery, this

I'm trying to get this line of code working.

```
$(".selectnumber").text($(this).parent().find('select').children(':selected').text());
```

It just wants to take the text value of the select and put it in the selectnumber span.

```
alert($(".selectnumber").parent().find('select').children(':selected').text());
```

works fine and returns the correct value so I have to assume that the $(this) isn't referencing the .selectnumber span as I would expect.

Heres the HTML as well in case it affects anything but I don't think it will.

```
<div class="holder">
    <span class="selectnumber"></span>
    <select id="number_of_cards_required" name="number_of_cards_required">
        <option selected="selected">1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have to assume that the $(this) isn't referencing the .selectnumber span as I would expect.**

Yes, that's correct. You're expecting `this` to refer to the element(s) that you've selected, simply because you're calling a function on them. However, you're just passing an argument to a function, at that point it has no relation to the object you're calling the function on, so this doesn't make much sense.

You can, however, pass a function to the `.text()` jQuery method which *would* allow you to use `this` to refer to that specific matched element.

```
$(".selectnumber").text(function () {
    return $(this).parent().find('select').children(':selected').text()
});
```

Comment: Ah brilliant! I knew there was something about the text selector that I wasn't seeing! 

Works perfectly! 

So basically the this selector only works if you pass it as a function, not on short function call.

Much appreicated!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(".selectnumber").html( your text )
```

not

```
$(".selectnumber").text( your text )
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` must be used within a context where it makes sense, as a trigger. You can try something like:

```
$(".selectnumber").html($("#number_of_cards_required").val());
```

**EDIT:**

If you put in a `value` for the options and still need the text, you can use:

```
$('#number_of_cards_required option:selected').text()
```

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question. I can't just us an selector to grab the .selectnumber or I could be grabbing it from a different selectbox on the same page which would have the same values. I need to make sure the select I'm grabbing is the one in the same <div class="holder> or it won't work correctly, hence needing to reference the current location.

Comment: Since the `number_of_cards_required` had an ID I figured they would be unique. Otherwise, how do you know which `selectnumber` to update from which `number_of_cards_required`, and when do you do it?  You could add a unique ID to the `selectnumber` and then use that as a selector. A better solution may be to add a `click` trigger on your `number_of_cards_required` which updates the closest `selectnumber`, but it's hard to know unless you specify how you want the solution to work.

Comment: No, was trying to do it generically so it works for all the select boxes on the page, hence why I never referenced the ID in the code :) 

Easy to do it just for one, would just be putting an ID on the target and hit it directly rather than messing around with 'this' ;) Kinda assumed anyone would see this from looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.html()` instead of `text()`. Maybe you also want the span update every time the select changes:

```
    $(".selectnumber").html($('#number_of_cards_required').val());


       $('#number_of_cards_required').change(function(){
    $(".selectnumber").html($('#number_of_cards_required').val());
});
```

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnrgA/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

//initial loading
$(".selectnumber").text($(".selectnumber").parent().find('select').children(':selected').text());  

//changing span if select changes

$("select").change(function() {
$(".selectnumber").text($(this).parent().find('select').children(':selected').text());        
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ACf4Y/